# Rollup - not packaging entire repo (child component missing)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rollup, rollupjs

I have a component library written in `vue` that I am wrapping up with `rollup`

I am having an issue with `mixins` not being wrapped up into the final library. Intially i thought that the path was the issue as most of the mixins are local.

Originally:

`import mixin from '../../mixins/color'`

```
Repo folder structure
   - dist //output
   - src //All files related to the actual component within the library
     - components
       - comps
          - alert //general components
          - inputs //input components
          - layout //layout components /row/col
     - mixins
     - utilities
     - entry.js //rollup points to this 
  - ...  //I used nuxt to develop the components to focus on SSR so there are more folders but are excluded in the rollup process
```

Apparently native `rollup` doesn't like indirect imports so I attempted to add `rollup-plugin-includepaths`. My understanding is that I would need to mention the paths required in the imports to work correctly.

Therefore, I added `rollup-plugin-includepaths` to `rollup.config.js` plugins and added the root path and the output director as the options

```
includePaths({
        paths: ['src/components/', 'src/mixins/', 'src/utilities/'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue']
      }),
```

**this did not work **

I decided to remove all relative imports and create aliases for each required directory. This did not work either

What is happening is all `mixins` imported into the component and added as `mixin: [mixins] //whatever they may be` are not included in the compiled product?!?!?!

What am I missing????

```
// rollup.config.js
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'
import vue from 'rollup-plugin-vue'
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import minimist from 'minimist'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import includePaths from 'rollup-plugin-includepaths'
import del from 'rollup-plugin-delete'

// Get browserslist config and remove ie from es build targets
const esbrowserslist = fs
  .readFileSync('./.browserslistrc')
  .toString()
  .split('\n')
  .filter(entry => entry && entry.substring(0, 2) !== 'ie')

const argv = minimist(process.argv.slice(2))

const projectRoot = path.resolve(__dirname)

const baseConfig = {
  input: 'src/entry.js',
  plugins: {
    preVue: [
      alias({
        resolve: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue'],
        entries: [
          { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src') },
          {
            find: '@mixins',
            replacement: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src', 'mixins')
          },
          {
            find: '@comps',
            replacement: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src', 'components', 'comps')
          },
          {
            find: '@inputs',
            replacement: path.resolve(
              projectRoot,
              'src',
              'components',
              'inputs'
            )
          },
          {
            find: '@utilities',
            replacement: path.resolve(projectRoot, 'src', 'utilities')
          }
        ]
      }),
      includePaths({
        paths: ['src/components/', 'src/mixins/', 'src/utilities/'],
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue']
      }),
      commonjs(),
      postcss()
    ],
    replace: {
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
      'process.env.ES_BUILD': JSON.stringify('false')
    },
    vue: {
      css: false,
      template: {
        isProduction: true
      }
    },
    babel: {
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx', '.vue']
    }
  }
}

// ESM/UMD/IIFE shared settings: externals
// Refer to https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
const external = [
  // list external dependencies, exactly the way it is written in the import statement.
  // eg. 'jquery'
  'vue'
]

// UMD/IIFE shared settings: output.globals
// Refer to https://rollupjs.org/guide/en#output-globals for details
const globals = {
  // Provide global variable names to replace your external imports
  // eg. jquery: '$'
  vue: 'Vue'
}

// Customize configs for individual targets
const buildFormats = []
if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'es') {
  const esConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      compact: true,
      file: 'dist/comps.esm.js',
      format: 'esm',
      exports: 'named'
    },
    plugins: [
      del({ targets: 'dist/*' }),
      replace({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.replace,
        'process.env.ES_BUILD': JSON.stringify('true')
      }),
      ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
      vue(baseConfig.plugins.vue),
      babel({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.babel,
        presets: [
          [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            {
              targets: esbrowserslist
            }
          ]
        ]
      })
    ]
  }
  buildFormats.push(esConfig)
}

if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'cjs') {
  const umdConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      compact: true,
      file: 'dist/comps.ssr.js',
      format: 'cjs',
      name: 'Components',
      exports: 'named',
      globals
    },
    plugins: [
      replace(baseConfig.plugins.replace),
      ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
      vue({
        ...baseConfig.plugins.vue,
        template: {
          ...baseConfig.plugins.vue.template,
          optimizeSSR: true
        }
      }),
      babel(baseConfig.plugins.babel)
    ]
  }
  buildFormats.push(umdConfig)
}

if (!argv.format || argv.format === 'iife') {
  const unpkgConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    external,
    output: {
      compact: true,
      file: 'dist/comps.min.js',
      format: 'iife',
      name: 'Components',
      exports: 'named',
      globals
    },
    plugins: [
      replace(baseConfig.plugins.replace),
      ...baseConfig.plugins.preVue,
      vue(baseConfig.plugins.vue),
      babel(baseConfig.plugins.babel),
      terser({
        output: {
          ecma: 5
        }
      })
    ]
  }
  buildFormats.push(unpkgConfig)
}
// Export config
export default buildFormats
```

**Update**

I moved the imported components out of the `mixin` and added them directly to the component that included them and got the same result. Therefore, i really have no clue what needs to happen.

**TL;DR**

None of the child components are being included in the rolled up dist '.js' files

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is hard to include what is relevant and the question above is guilty.

The problem is within the larger component I had imported the children lazily

ex:

```
components:{
 comp: ()=>import('comp') ///Does not work
}
```

changed to your standard

```
import comp from 'comp'
components:{
   comp
}
```